# memory effective list of integers with fast search and slow insert/delete

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures

I'm trying to find the best [data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures) for a sorted list of positive integers (millions of elements). Requirements are (in order of importance):

1. Small memory footprint
2. Fast `O(log n)` search
3. Insert/delete faster than `memcpy()`

I'm thinking about keeping two arrays: one for search and one for insert. Every few operations I will re-organize the main one and clean the second one. Any thoughts? Am I on the right track?

ps. There are no duplicates. It doesn't need to be thread-safe. Reads will happen very often, while writes very rarely. Integers are distribute in the structure unevenly, meaning that some structures will contain just a few elements, while others may have millions of them, taking positions from zero to `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: How constrictive is the memory footprint requirement?  You have a trade off between memory and time and the difference between a few megs and a few hundred megs makes a huge difference on how you should go about this.

Comment: Memory is very critical. Ideally I would like to have a size of this structure to be `X * 4`, where X is the number of elements and 4 is bytes per element

Comment: duplicates allowed or not? safe concurrent access required or not? rough frequency of writes vs. reads?

Comment: @mikera no duplicates, no thread safeness, very often reads, very rare writes

Comment: If writes are that rare...do you have actual benchmarks suggesting `memcpy` is too slow?

Comment: there are millions of elements. yes, I think (no benchmarks yet) that `memcpy()` will be rather slow

Comment: What is the largest positive integer you need to be able to store?  If it is "reasonable", (say, less that 800M) you might be able to use a BitSet.

Comment: I assume that you're using the term '`memcpy`' metaphorically here, since there is no `memcpy` in Java. Do you mean `System.arrayCopy`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use an [Van Emde Boas Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree)

It has the following characteristics:

```
Space   O(M)
Search  O(log log M)
Insert  O(log log M)
Delete  O(log log M)
```

Comment: Hmmm.  Tentative +1, just because I seem to recall VEB is relatively compact memory-wise just because it can use a packed bit array.  (Also, it's sorted, and supports sorted operations efficiently.)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an interesting and non-trivial problem. The optimal answer will depend on your specific requirements the precise mix of operations you perform.

If the **data is dense and duplicates are not allowed**, then a big bitmap may be optimal. Just set a bit to show the presence / absence of each possible integer value. This approach will be very fast and O(1) for both reads and writes, but memory usage will obviously be driven by how large a range you have / how sparse your data tends to be.

If the **data is dense and duplicates are allowed / common**, then an array storing the number of occurrences for each possible value may work well. Similar in performance to bitmap approach, however you probably need 32x as much memory assuming ints for occurrence counts.

If you are **read-heavy and data is sparse** then a sorted array based approach (with binary search for lookup) may be best. If you have knowledge about the rough distribution of the values then you may be able to go even faster by using heuristics to guess the likely position of the target value in the array (e.g. you can significantly beat log2(N) if you exploit the knowledge that the distribution is roughly uniform)

If you have a **lot of writes and data is sparse** then you probably want a tree-based structure that splits based on subsets of the bits in your integers (e.g. a 32-way trie splitting on the next most significant 5 bits at each node). Clojure's persistent data structures use this technique to great effect.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `char[65536][]`? where the top or bottom 16 bits is an index to an array of the other 16 bits. This could use less than 4 * X per entry.

Lookup

```
 private final char[][] bitsArray = new char[65536][];

 public int countFor(int num) {
     int topBits = num >>> 16;
     int lowerBits = num & 0xFFFF;
     char[] lowerBitsArray = bitsArray[topBits];
     int count = 0;
     for(char l : lowerBitsArray)
        if(l == lowerBits)
           count++;
     return count;
 }
```

If the count can never be more than 1, a BitSet is likely to be a better choice. (Possibly an array of BitSet depending on the pattern of data) E.g. if you were to record IP addresses seen, you might not need to worry about 0.*, 10.*, 127.* or 224-255.*

---

Whether an `int[]` or `char[]` is faster to access including casting to int.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    char[] chars = new char[1000000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        timeSum(chars);
    int[] ints = new int[1000000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        timeSum(ints);
}

private static int timeSum(char[] chars) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int sum = 0;
    for (char ch : chars) {
        sum += ch;
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %,d us to sum %,d chars%n", time / 1000, chars.length);
    return sum;
}

private static int timeSum(int[] ints) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : ints) {
        sum += i;
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Took %,d us to sum %,d ints%n", time / 1000, ints.length);
    return sum;
}
```

prints

```
Took 5,378 us to sum 1,000,000 chars
Took 11,551 us to sum 1,000,000 chars
Took 437 us to sum 1,000,000 chars
Took 407 us to sum 1,000,000 chars
Took 407 us to sum 1,000,000 chars
Took 5,539 us to sum 1,000,000 ints
Took 532 us to sum 1,000,000 ints
Took 530 us to sum 1,000,000 ints
Took 511 us to sum 1,000,000 ints
Took 507 us to sum 1,000,000 ints
```

My conclusion is that cache efficiency is more important than cast cost.

Comment: how would that use less then 4*X?  ints are 4 per int, so just storing the ints would take 4X.

Comment: `char` is `16 bits` so you only need at least 2 bytes per entry this way. There is quite a bit of overhead but it scales fairly well.

Comment: adding a char to int conversion on every compare would be huge

Comment: I am willing to bet its so small you can't even benchmark it. Given its more likely to fit into cache it could be faster rather than slower. ;)

Comment: what he is saying is the size of the footprint would be X * 2 instead of X * 4, and the conversion from char to int could be done in cashe so you wouldn't even notice it unless you did billions of calculations a second.  It would still take (to the human eye) the same time to transverse the list as it would if you were using ints instead of chars

Comment: much worse actually. Its 64K * 16 bytes per array.

Comment: Alot depends on what you expect the upper bound to be. You either want something which is very small in which case log N doesn't matter too much. Or you want something which scales well.

Comment: He already said 64K worth of ints, so 64000/4 = 16 thousand ints is what he is working with currently, and he is talking about inserting more.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more this idea seems even better than mine.  +1

Comment: I have no idea what "where the top or bottom 16 bits is an index to an array of the other 16 bits" means. Do you fancy explaining in a bit more detail how insertion and lookup would work?

Comment: @TomAnderson I have added a lookup count example.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Peter Lawrey has a good start: subdivide.  Partly to be different, I'd subdivide into 256 things, each of which tracks 2^23 things.  Depending on the distribution of your integers, either use the top or bottom 8 bits to subdivide.

As for the sub things, start with a Set (or similar) when the ints are sparse.  But, once that Set reaches a certain size, (it starts getting dense) switch to a BitSet.  I don't know if you will need to support removing values, in which case you would need to switch back from BitSet to Set.

p.s. If all else fails, a simple BitSet of **all** the positive integers is "only" 268MB (If my calculations are right...)

Answer (score 0):

What about a linked list? the momory constraints would be the size of the ints + a little overhead for the previous & next pointers.  As far as inserting and deleting, the time requirement would be only to go down the list until you find one smaller then the one you're insterting and put it in just before that record.  Deleting would only require the pointers of previous and next to change, and searching would be just as easy as inserting.

Comment: every item will have a pointer to another, which is extra 4 bytes (at least) per item

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too worried about speed, and are petrified of memory usage, you can load an array of ints in, create another array, sort through the array until you have a number X (1K or so to prevent memory overload) and then save that part of the array as a text file (objectOutputStream will save ints as ints), clear the array, and then do the same for the next X number of ints in the array.  Just make sure you mark the output stream to append the file (true) vs overwrite which is what the default is.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at some of the [modern generation of tries](http://bhavin.directi.com/to-trie-or-not-to-trie-a-comparison-of-efficient-data-structures/) (that link doesn't mention [fusion trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_tree)). However, i think they're all pretty complicated to implement. If you're llucky, you might find that some bold individual has written and open-sourced an implementation you can use.

Another thing to look at would be a classic [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

If your data sets are of a relatively consistent size, you could even write a one-level B-tree (so with a single root node and multiple child nodes), which simplifies the implementation quite a bit (in that you can just store an `int[][]`, and replace the internal keys with peeks into the leaves, if that makes any sense).